# My IP did not bind to my domain name

Tags: dns, ip

When I request my domain name `example.com` it is not showing, I send a ping it is not working "timed out", I tried `nslookup` it is not giving the right IP.

I have a dedicated server and I have a lot of websites that share the same IP address.  All those websites are working correctly and pointing to the correct IP except this site.

At the beginning I have add 2 A records for this website on my account on `name.com` to link the domain with the IP (two records for the nameservers `ns1.example.com`, `ns2.example.com`) did not work.  And then I added two more (one with * and the final one is empty just linked with the IP) nothing happened.

Does any one have any recommendation for this?

Comment: The first two A records you added, are they the IP addresses of your name servers or `name.com`'s name servers?  This matters.  If you get this wrong the domain will not work.  Are you using `nslookup` (or `dig`) to query the authoritative servers directly?  If not you could be seeing cached responses.  I always recommend [IntoDNS](http://www.intodns.com/spdserver.com) for help with DNS questions, you will probably find them helpful.

Comment: the records are my nameservers and I did use nslookup

Answer (score 1):

If the domain listed in your other question is the same one you're having troubles with now, the biggest problem is that both of your listed nameservers are failing to respond to requests of any type.

If you are running bind, you will find errors logged in the standard logs when bind starts or you can use the `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone` tools to verify your configuration before restarting bind.

If these domains are important to you, I would recommend renting the services of a professional DNS provider.  DNS downtime is particularly painful because there's so much caching in the system which can easily extend a 5 minute downtime to 24 hours.  Dyn.com and Amazon's Route53 offer cheap, reliable DNS hosting and I'm sure there is plenty of competition in this area.

Comment: Wait sir I really thank you very much but I did not understand your explanation up there. Do you mean that I should buy a new domain instead of this domain. because i see all the errors on intoDNS and compare it with the results of other domains on the same server. the other domain works with no errors just this one has errors

Comment: I use the same name servers for other domains on the same host server

Comment: My guess is that you have a typo in the zone file for this domain.  If you edit the zone file into your question we might be able to spot it for you.  The `named-checkzone` file or your logs should be able to verify that you have a typo.  I'm not suggesting that you sell the domain, simply that you have someone else run bind for you.

Comment: I compare the DNS zone with other website DNS zone and I found the I made a big mistake I did not add A records for ns1 and ns2 . Thank you for help.